# how to calculate the closest points to a given point using leaflet-knn?

Tags: php, ajax, leaflet

I have two point Layers (Customers,Suppliers), i want to get all the nearest suppliers to a specific customer within a distance entered by user,i heared about leaflet knn but i couldn't find a full example to understand it well,any suggestions?
This is my code in the part of getting the customers data through ajax

```
    $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'Customers_geojson.php',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (response) {
                    geojsonLayer = L.geoJson(
                        response,
                        {
                        pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) 
                            {
                             return L.circleMarker(latlng, geojsonMarkerOptions1);
                            }
                            },
                            {   
                            onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) 
                            {
                            layer.bindPopup('<label>Nick Name:</label>' + feature.properties.nick_name_);
                            }
                    }).addTo(mymap);
                    $("#info").fadeOut(500);
                    var gj = L.geoJson(response);
                    var nearest = leafletKnn(gj).nearest(L.latLng(8.71224, 125.692), 10000);
                    alert(nearest);

                    }
                });
```

Comment: If your question is «Can somebody help me with X?», the [answer will be either «yes» or «no»](http://www.strcat.de/questions-with-yes-or-no-answers.html). Please reformulate your question.

Comment: Please read [«How do I ask a good question?»](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You might want to change the title to something like «Given a lot of points, how to calculate the closest N ones to a given one?»

Comment: Thanks alot, i will change it.

Comment: @IvanSanchez can you help me please?

Comment: Don't beg. Begging, or asking again and again, or showing a sense or urgency, won't get you faster or better answers. Please do read http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html

Answer (score 2):

> How to calculate the closest points to a given point using leaflet-knn?

The answer is "You can not".

A [nearest neighbour search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nearest_neighbor_search) algorithm, such as the one that [`rbush-knn`](https://github.com/mourner/rbush-knn) (and the *much* older [`leaflet-knn`](https://github.com/mapbox/leaflet-knn)) implements, helps you answer queries like:

> I live at (x,y); what are the **5 closest** shops to my house?

or

> I'm at (x,y); where is the **closest** subway station?

or even

> I'm at (x,y); where is the **closest** subway station? **Limit** the search to 500 meters because I won't bother walking that far.

...but the query *you* want to answer is very different (emphasis mine):

> I want to get **all** the nearest suppliers to a specific customer **within a distance** entered by user.

Using a nearest-neighbour search algorithm is **the wrong tool for the job**. What you want is either:

- Given a point, generate a circle centred on that point, with radius `N`. That circle will contain *all* points that are at a distance equal or less than `N` from the centre, and nothing else.
- Given a point, generate a square centred on that point, with sides of length `N*2`. That square will contain *all* points that are at a distance equal or less than `N` from the centre, *plus* some which are not.

In GIS jargon, making a circle is known as making a **buffer**, then finding the **intersection** of the buffer and your points set.

Idem, making a square is known as making a bounding box, and **querying points inside the bounding box**.

Making a buffer sounds best, but is computationally more expensive. Very much so. Creating a bounding box and querying a set of points is very very cheap (read "fast") and can be achieved with a simple query to a r-tree structure (see e.g. [the documentation and examples for `rbush`](https://github.com/mourner/rbush)).