# How to display the closest marker within the given range?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, leaflet

I am working on displaying the marker within the given range from the selected marker. The user can set the distance range from by sliding the slider. I have the location of marker stored in my database. I am not sure about how can I find the marker that are within the user selected range.

Can anybody help me how can do this task.

Thank You.

```js
const myloc = new L.LatLng(13.7563, 100.5018);
const myloc1 = new L.LatLng(13.8023, 100.5538);
const myloc2 = new L.LatLng(13.7649, 100.5383);
const myloc3 = new L.LatLng(15.8700, 100.9925);
const myloc4 = new L.LatLng(13.668217, 100.614021);
const myloc5 = new L.LatLng(13.859108, 100.521652);
const myloc6 = new L.LatLng(17.878281, 102.741264);
const myloc7 = new L.LatLng(13.814029, 100.037292);
const myloc8 = new L.LatLng(18.793867, 98.997116);
const myloc9 = new L.LatLng(14.979900, 102.097771);
const myloc10 = new L.LatLng(18.772558, 98.982361);
const myloc11 = new L.LatLng(18.772558, 98.982361);
const myloc12 = new L.LatLng(16.439625, 102.828728);
const myloc13 = new L.LatLng(13.361143, 100.984673);

const map = L.map('map').setView(myloc, 11);

const scale = ' meter';

L.tileLayer('https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token={accessToken}', {
  attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, <a href="https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, Imagery © <a href="https://www.mapbox.com/">Mapbox</a>',
  maxZoom: 18,
  id: 'mapbox.streets',
  accessToken: 'accesstoken'
}).addTo(map);

let marker = L.marker(myloc).addTo(map);

L.marker(myloc).addTo(map);
L.marker(myloc1).addTo(map);
L.marker(myloc2).addTo(map);
L.marker(myloc3).addTo(map);
L.marker(myloc4).addTo(map);
L.marker(myloc5).addTo(map);
L.marker(myloc6).addTo(map);
L.marker(myloc7).addTo(map);
L.marker(myloc8).addTo(map);
L.marker(myloc9).addTo(map);
L.marker(myloc10).addTo(map);
L.marker(myloc11).addTo(map);
L.marker(myloc12).addTo(map);
L.marker(myloc13).addTo(map);

let circle = L.circle(myloc, {
  color: '#7a7777',
  weight: 0.1,
  fillColor: '#7a7777',
  fillOpacity: 0.2,
  radius: 0
}).addTo(map);

var slider = document.getElementById('myRange');
var output = document.getElementById('demo');
output.innerHTML = slider.value + scale;

slider.oninput = function(val) {
  if (val == 0) {
    output.innerHTML = 0 + scale;
    map.removeLayer(circle);
    return;
  }
  output.innerHTML = this.value + scale;
  circle.setRadius(this.value);

}
```

```css
#map {
  width: 500px;
  height: 400px;
  border: 1px solid #AAA;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.3/dist/leaflet.css" />
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.3/dist/leaflet.js"></script>

<div id="map"></div>

<input type="range" min="0" max="15000" value="0" class="slider" id="myRange">
<br>
<span id="demo"></span>
```

Comment: Mapbox has a great example  of something very similar - https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/example/v1.0.0/marker-radius-search/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are describing something very close to a [*k*-Nearest Neighbour search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nearest_neighbor_search) problem (or *k*-NN search for short).

In order to approach this problem with *k*-NN searches and assuming JavaScript as the platform of choice, you can leverage [`leaflet-knn`](https://github.com/mapbox/leaflet-knn) or just create a r-tree with rbush and leverage [`rbush-knn`](https://github.com/mourner/rbush-knn).

(If you choose the later, beware of the coordinate system used by your data - the distances shall use that coordinate system - if you store coordinates as degrees of latitude-longitude, the query distance has to be provided in degrees of lat-lng).

As noted in [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40650796/how-to-calculate-the-closest-points-to-a-given-point-using-leaflet-knn#40652607), a *k*-NN search cannot really provide *all* the results within a distance to the given point. To do that, leverage [`turfjs`](http://turfjs.org/docs/): create a circular buffer along your search point, then calculate the interseccion between the buffer and your data points.

Comment: thank you I tried leaflet-knn algorithm. It worked for me